# How to align multiple subfigures in a grid?

Tags: graphics, align, subcaption

I have three images and I want to align them in the way that one image is above the other two. Here's an example:

[image: example alignment]

How can I achieve this? For my other figures I use the subcaption package, but I am not able to align the pictures that way with it.

---

Thanks for all your replys! The **answer** that is working for me is the one supposed by karlkoeller:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A mouse}\label{fig:mouse}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{A gull}\label{fig:gull}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{A tiger}\label{fig:tiger}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Picture of animals}
\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could we have a minimal (non)working example?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are already using the `subcaption` package, and it is very easy with it.

Here's the code you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{A mouse}\label{fig:mouse}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{A gull}\label{fig:gull}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{A tiger}\label{fig:tiger}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Picture of animals}
\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you need to have the subcaption numbers as in your picture, you have to adjust the counter `subfigure` with `\setcounter{subfigure}{<num>}` inside the `subfigure`s

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\setcounter{subfigure}{2}%
\caption{A mouse}\label{fig:mouse}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}%
\caption{A gull}\label{fig:gull}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{A tiger}\label{fig:tiger}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Picture of animals}
\label{fig:animals}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that adding an empty line after the first subfigure environment serves as a new line. That is why the two subfigures that follow are placed below the first one. Similarly, by not adding an empty line between the second and third subfigure enviornments, the second and third subfigures shall appear next to each other (as long as they can fit within the page width).

Answer (score 6):

Within a figure environment you can start a tabular environment to have more control over the distribution of space. Fill the tabs with subfigures. You can even use the `multirow` package for even further tweaking and control.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[c]{ccccc}
    \multirow{2}{*}[14pt]{
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[height=2cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
      \caption{CEO fixed / total}
      \label{fig:ceoa}
    \end{subfigure}
}&
   \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.11\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[height=1cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \label{fig:ceob}
    \end{subfigure}&
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.11\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[height=1cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \label{fig:ceoc}
    \end{subfigure}&
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.11\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[height=1cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \label{fig:ceoe}
    \end{subfigure}&
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.11\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[height=1cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \label{fig:cdfeod}
    \end{subfigure}\\
    &
        \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.11\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[height=1cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \label{fig:caeob}
    \end{subfigure}&
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.11\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[height=1cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \label{fig:ceoac}
    \end{subfigure}&
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.11\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[height=1cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \label{fig:ceose}
    \end{subfigure}&
    \begin{subfigure}[c]{0.11\textwidth}
      \includegraphics[height=1cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \label{fig:ceod}
    \end{subfigure}\\
  \end{tabular}    
  \caption{Compensation measures}
  \label{fig:ceo}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Almost all your `subfigure` environments are pointless in a tabular cell. You don't have a caption either, so i don't get the point of using it. It just makes the code longer and harder to read.

Comment: In this very example I agree. I put them though to show that it is posible to tabulate with them, which means that it is possible to caption and label.

Comment: You can use caption and label in the table cells as well. `subfigure` is just a minipage which also sets the captiontype. Using `captionof` would be just enough.

Answer (score 5):

It's relatively easy with the `floatrow` package, and its `subfloatrow`environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\floatsetup{capposition = below, floatrowsep =qquad,}
\centering
\begin{subfloatrow}
\centering
  \ffigbox[\textwidth]{\caption{The Death of Procris}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Piero_di_Cosimo_1}
  }
\end{subfloatrow}
\vskip1cm
\begin{subfloatrow}
    \ffigbox[0.5\textwidth]{\caption{Portrait of Simonetta Vespucci}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Piero_di_Cosimo_3}%
  }
    \ffigbox[0.5\textwidth]{\caption{Portrait of Simonetta Vespucci}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{Piero_di_Cosimo_3}%
  }
\end{subfloatrow}
\caption{Three paintings by Piero di Cosimo}
\label{PC}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use minipages to specify how the images should be aligned. If you include the image into a box first, then you can get the width of the image (which should be the width of the minipage) using `\wd`, i.e.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \newcommand*\FigVSkip{0.5em}
  \newcommand*\FigHSkip{0.1em}
  \newsavebox\FigBox
  \centering
  % Top image is centered, so no need to get width
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    \centering\includegraphics{a_mouse}
    \subcaption{A mouse}
  \end{minipage} \\[\FigVSkip]%
  % Save first image in a box to get the width
  \sbox{\FigBox}{\includegraphics{a_gull}}
  \begin{minipage}{\wd\FigBox}
    \centering\usebox{\FigBox}
    \subcaption{A gull}
  \end{minipage}\hspace*{\FigHSkip}
  % Save second image 
  \sbox{\FigBox}{\includegraphics{a_tiger}}
  \begin{minipage}{\wd\FigBox}
    \centering\usebox{\FigBox}
    \subcaption{A tiger}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Pictures of animals}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I also included the two parameters `\FigHSkip` and `\FigVSkip` to set the horizontal and vertical spacing of the images. The rest of the code is almost copied and pasted from subcaption documentation page 4 ([subcaption on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption))

[image: result]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Maybe you could add an image to show the final rendering.