# Pdf compiled file error

Tags: pdftex, lyx

[image]

Here is my attached pdf file shot. When I compile my LyX document these figures go out of the window. Actually these are 10 sub figures whereas only 5 are visible in the pdf file after compiling. Please help where am I doing wrong

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222656/how-to-align-multiple-subfigures-in-a-grid

Comment: where would I write this code?