# Create grid of math equations that count to set of align equations

Tags: table-of-contents, equations, align, amsmath, grids

I start my appendix (separate to `main.tex` where I load my packages) with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
% your preamble here
\begin{document}
\chapter{Appendix}   
\setcounter{figure}{0} 

\begin{align}
  E_1&=A+B \label{eq:1}\\
   \begin{split}
    E_2&=(C-D)E_1 \label{eq:2}\\
    &\quad +[(1-R)+R(1-Y)\\
    &\quad +\pi(1-\delta)]E_2\\
    &\quad +F\cdot E_3
   \end{split}\\
  E_3 &=(\pi\cdot \chi)-(R\cdot E_1)-(RY\delta\cdot E_2) \label{eq:3}
\end{align
}
```

Which looks like:

[image]

I then want to have a separate grid of equations that continues on from this, adapted from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222656/how-to-align-multiple-subfigures-in-a-grid).

However, because these are subfigures part of a figure, the set of all of them currently goes in my list of figures, instead of each of them going separately into my list of equations.

I still want to keep the figure caption for the group of equations (which goes into my list of figures), but want to have every caption within the subfigure appear in my list of equations, numbered e.g. having each cost function labelled like `(8.5)`,`(8.6)`,`(8.7)` etc.

Current code that comes next:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\centering
  $$C_cip = {V_cp - V_ci}$$
\caption{VD}\label{fig:cost1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
\centering
  $$C_cip = {|V_cp - V_ci|}$$
\caption{AVD}\label{fig:cost2}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  $$C_cip = \frac{V_cp - V_ci}{V_ci}$$
\caption{PE}\label{fig:cost3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  $$C_cip = \frac{|V_cp - V_ci|}{|V_ci|}$$
\caption{APE}\label{fig:cost3}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
  \centering
  $$C_cip = \frac{|V_cp - V_ci|}{|V_ci|}$$
\caption{APE}\label{fig:cost3}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Cost functions}
\label{fig:costs}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which displays this:

[image]

In addition, I am unsure why my captions are appearing on the far LHS of each equation instead of right below it. For full information, here is the set of packages I load and settings before `begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{report}
% Not sure what this is for
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
% For quotes in chapters
\usepackage{epigraph}
% This is for named paragraphs
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
% This is for aligned equations
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ulem}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{15pt}{{\theparagraph\hspace*{1em}#1.}}
\titleformat{name=\paragraph,numberless}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{15pt}{{#1.}}
%  This is for the trees
\usepackage{forest}
% This is for input encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% This is for a list of equations
\usepackage{tocloft}
% This is for binding
\usepackage[]{geometry}
% a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm
% This is for a list of equations
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}% Width of equation number in List of Equations

 \usepackage{array,ltablex, makecell}%
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\usepackage[]{multirow}
% This is for quotes
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
% This is for tables
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
% This is formatting for long tables
\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\usepackage{array}
% This is for images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false} % optional
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}} % "decimal" column type
\renewcommand{\ast}{{}^{\textstyle *}} % for raised "asterisks"
% This overrides warnings like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52576/difference-between-bookmark-levels-greater-than-one-what-does-this-mean
\usepackage{bookmark}
% This is for maths
\usepackage{amsmath}
% This allows for subcaptions in grids
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{standalone}
% This is for bibliographies
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% This is for hyperlinks
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=cyan,
}

\urlstyle{same}

% This is a custom command to make declaration
\newcommand \makedeclaration {%
\clearpage%
I, \@author , confirm that the work presented in this thesis is my own.
Where information has been derived from other sources, I confirm that this has been indicated in the work.
\gdef \@author{}%
\clearpage%
}

% This is to make glossaries
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{apeg}{name={APE},
    description={Absolute Percentage Error is the absolute percentage difference between one value and another}}

%%% define the acronym and use the see= option
\newglossaryentry{ape}{type=\acronymtype, name={APE}, description={Absolute Percentage Error}, first={Absolute Percentage Error (APE)\glsadd{apeg}}, see=[Glossary:]{apeg}}
% This is to create quotes
\usepackage{gb4e}
\noautomath

\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe like this?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173104/10995
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\DeclareRobustCommand\myequations[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures
\listofmyequations

\begin{align}
  E_1&=A+B \label{eq:1}\\
  \begin{split}
    E_2&=(C-D)E_1 \label{eq:2}\\
    &\quad +[(1-R)+R(1-Y)\\
    &\quad +\pi(1-\delta)]E_2\\
    &\quad +F\cdot E_3
  \end{split}\\
  E_3 &=(\pi\cdot \chi)-(R\cdot E_1)-(RY\delta\cdot E_2) \label{eq:3}
\end{align}

\begin{figure}[b]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
      C_cip = V_cp - V_ci
    \end{equation}
    \myequations{VD}
    \caption{VD}
    \label{fig:cost1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
      C_cip = |V_cp - V_ci|
    \end{equation}
    \myequations{AVD}
    \caption{AVD}
    \label{fig:cost2}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
      C_cip = \frac{V_cp - V_ci}{V_ci}
    \end{equation}
    \myequations{PE}
    \caption{PE}
    \label{fig:cost3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
      C_cip = \frac{|V_cp - V_ci|}{|V_ci|}
    \end{equation}
    \myequations{APE}
    \caption{APE}
    \label{fig:cost3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}
      C_cip = \frac{|V_cp - V_ci|}{|V_ci|}
    \end{equation}
    \myequations{APE}
    \caption{APE}
    \label{fig:cost3}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Cost functions}
  \label{fig:costs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution is awesome @Henri Menke, with the use of blocks. However, for some reason my figure caption is appearing to the far left of my page rather than below the blocks of equations. Why is this the case?

Comment: I worked it out, `\captionsetup{labelsep=newline,singlelinecheck=false}` was causing my left alignment.

Comment: Actually the labels like AVD, VD etc are appearing far too close to the equations below. How can I make them appear on the LHS of the equation just to the left so it is more clear?